# Adobe Flash Player : PPAPI vs NPAPI in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, flash

What is the difference of PPAPI and NPAPI version of Adobe Flash Player in Google Chrome? They have different versions and they are both enabled.

If a Flash movie / game is loaded in Chrome...

1. Which version of Flash Player will Chrome use?
2. Will the 2 versions compete with each other?
3. Should I disable one of them ( and which one )?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are a couple of links you may want to look at for background:

- [The road to safer, more stable, and flashier Flash](http://blog.chromium.org/2012/08/the-road-to-safer-more-stable-and.html) and
- [Explaining the confusion over Flash versions](http://blogs.computerworld.com/desktop-apps/20845/explaining-confusion-over-flash-versions)

Re. which version of Flash will be used ... there again there are changes (coming). Google plans to block all NPAPI plugins:  [Saying Goodbye to Our Old Friend NPAPI](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html). So that won't be an issue in 2014. Quite sometime ago, I recollect that if two plugins were available, they would not have the same "priority" and so the one with the higher priority would run. For an oldish view on the topic, look at [Why are Two Flash Player Plugins Running In Google Chrome?](http://www.ghacks.net/2011/10/25/why-are-two-flash-player-plugins-running-in-google-chrome/).

Re. which one you should disable ... I'd suggest not bothering unless you have a problem with the PPAPI one. It's not that both would be consuming resources when you watch Flash content.

(*For Linux users ...*
*Adobe will only provide "security" updates for Flash on Linux. So 11.2.202 was the "final" full version of the NPAPI version.*

*Google, in collaboration with Adobe, will provide the PPAPI version of Flash for Linux.*)

Comment: As there have been several updates to Adobes release intentions, it's now worth mentioning that the Linux flash player will get regular updates to the NPAPI version from now on, putting it on par with the PPAPI version, currently version 23. More information here http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2016/08/beta-news-flash-player-npapi-for-linux.html

Comment: I came here (to this question) to get basic difference between the two (what exactly they are and how they differ) but this answer does not answer it, just point to other pages (no offense).  So I had to google it a little. For future visitors, here are the links: [Netspace Plugin API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI) and [Pepper Plugin API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Native_Client#Pepper)